# NuGet: Updating appsettings.json, adding readme.txt

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I'm trying to create a NuGet which adds a section to appsettings.json.

I created my NuGet simply by creating a .NET Core Class Library and enabling "Generate NuGet package on build". This generates the NuGet correct and I can use the actual code in other projects.

I however have also added an "appsettings.json" and "readme.txt", and I wanted the appsettings.json to be appended to an existing appsettings.json, and the readme.txt to be just copied over. And I can't seem to get this to work.

What I have tried:

- Adding it to the csproj file, like in the documentation of Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=netcore-cli#adding-a-readme-and-other-files, https://github.com/NuGet/learn.microsoft.com-nuget/blob/master/docs/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio.md#adding-a-readme-and-other-files ... This does not work.
- Adding a nuspec.xsd, but that doesn't even overwrite the basic properties like version, description... [image: nuspec.xsd]

Am I missing something here? I'm finding a lot of guides on how to create nuget packages, and they all say different things but none work beyond the basics.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and the NuGet that comes with it.

**Edit:** I was testing out my NuGet using a local source, and apparently if you don't change the version number Visual Studio keeps that NuGet somewhere, so I was creating a new version of my NuGet but Visual Studio kept installing the old version.

So now using

```
<None Include="readme.txt" pack="true" PackagePath=".">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

does show the readme.txt when installing the NuGet. It still doesn't add it to the solution, but it's a start!

Thank you

Schoof

Comment: What version of NuGet are you using?

Comment: I am using the NuGet version that comes with Visual Studio 2019. I didn't install any specific NuGet.

Comment: They don't seem to have any plans on adding support  for [appSettings.json transformations](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/796) but I know how to add readme.txt at least:

    <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="readme.txt">
      <Pack>true</Pack>
        </Content>
      </ItemGroup>

Comment: That's a shame, thank you though! I'll just add it to the readme. :) (Which is now working!)